# False duplicate: What can I do if people insincerely ask for my patience?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/13020/2423) was closed as a duplicate, but [I explained why it isn't](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/13020/how-can-i-be-resilient-with-people-asking-for-my-patience?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment53284_13020):

> This isn't a duplicate. Someone can repeatedly ask you for patience even if they aren't too slow.

Comment: If you ask on meta requesting for your question to be reopened, you need to actually make a case for why it should be. Address earlier concerns and the issues that led to it being closed, and explain why your question, in its current form, deserves to be open - in more than one sentence. It behooves you to explain all this as clearly as possible.

Comment: If it were me having constantly my questions "*DV / closed / argued over*" (and so on...), I'd start thinking about **my** way of using this stack, and not why this stack doesn't understand me :)

Answer (score 10):

This isn't the first time you've asked questions about your grandmother having problems with a slow response from her school. This isn't the first time you've complained about the question being closed, on meta either.

All of these questions are incredibly similar, often with the majority of their text being identical across multiple posts. On a larger level than looking for duplicated strings, they all are effectively asking "How does my grandmother get a faster response from the staff at her university?" Changing the wording slightly doesn't make it a different question.

We are getting tired of closing the same questions with multiple problems for the same reasons over and over again. Similarly we are getting tired of explaining why we are closing these questions on meta over and over again.

Comment: In addition, the current question doesn't contain a question in the body, and the dupe asks how to "cope", which is too vague.